# Getting the complete feed of a facebook page

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to get all the posts of a page? facebook only returns recent posts as seen below.

https://graph.facebook.com/platform/feed

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use paging. Facebook limits the amount of data you can get in a single request. If you notice at the very bottom of the link you provided there are two properties, next and previous. You can use the urls provided in these properties to go to the next set of results. Additionally, you can also do paging manually. See this link for details on paging. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#documentation

Comment: I would recommend doing the paging manually, since the next/prev links were/are broken due to a bug.